# Optional Foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a MySQL database table with a column (integer) that references a column in another table with a foreign key.

I want the value to be optional. If I try to update the value to 0 (a value that doesn't exist in the other table), the query fails.

How can I use a foreign key while keeping the value in the column optional?

Comment: make the referencing field nullable and use null instead of 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Duplicating my comment so the question can be marked as answered.*

Foreign key constraints can be made optional by simply making the referencing field(s) nullable.